# Set up apache and django on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I'm not an admin so I have some problems on setting my site on digital ocean.
I've read manuals, install apache, install django, install mod_wsgi, but it still didn't work. Maybe  I don't understand some core things, so I ask to help me.

What I've already did:
install django and apache,
made file in apache\sites-available -
vz10.net (I took it from manual)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName vz10.net

WSGIDaemonProcess vz10.net processes=2 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup vz10.net

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vz10.net/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/vz10.net>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel warn

Alias /static/ /var/www/vz10.net/static/
<Directory /var/www/vz10.net/>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I cloned my project from github to /var/www/vz10.net , in this folder I made apache/django.wsgi (I took it from manual too)

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/vz10.net/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'students_score.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler
```

After that I reload apache and try, but all I've got is just observing my folder in browser
[image]

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `a2ensite vz10.net` to enable your Apache configuration.

Comment: I've already did it, and restart apache after that. This is what I see in terminal http://monosnap.com/image/IXIBLeymJYpiIYzAALie0I8Pthjpp5